# PHP DOM LoadHTML changes HTML content

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I have the following code that loads HTML content, if I have placeholders in the `Head` tag like:

```
{if ($Engine->current_language['en'])}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="localhost/mysite/css/rtl.css" />
{/if}
```

and have a CSS class applied to body in the content, but after calling the `LoadHTML` function, the placeholder gets removed from the `Head` tag and moved within the body tag. Also the CSS class on the body is removed.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: are you loading that template code into loadhtml? If so, then of course it's not going to work. It's **NOT** html. It's whatever template language you're using, which happens to contain some small html snippets.

Comment: Yes! I am using template. Is there any way that loadHTML don't formed HTML by itself. (let this placeholder as it is)

Comment: No, because your template is NOT html. you're complaining that you can't make a sandwich with the bag of flour/yeast/water you have. Well, of course not, it's not bread. it's just some ingredients.

Comment: What if I need to parse my template and create some DIV elements before any element that have specific value. 
Any suggestions please...